# jquery function not work inside append() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table. Here it is: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PvWKG/
There are 2 columns in the table. Text of Left side's column(Name Me) are editable. There is a Button too at the top. When user click on the button, a row'll be added which I made with `append()` function. But at the dynamic row, editable function are not working. Normally editable function are working when I make my code like this:

```
<a href="#" class="edit_text">Name Me</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit_text').editable();
});
```

But, when I'm putting this code: `<a href="#" class="edit_text">Name Me</a>` inside `append()` function, it won't work. I don't understand why it's happened as I ain't good at jQuery. How can I fix this?

Comment: When you call `$('.edit_text').editable()`, you are only affecting the elements on the page at that time.  Try to call `$('.edit_text').editable()` *again* after `append()`.

Comment: Why are you showing us the code that works instead of the code that doesn't?

Comment: Here is a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/PvWKG/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create new row you've already binded editable to existing rows not the new one. You've got to bind editable to the new row.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/9zP8k/

```
var row = $('<tr><td><a href="#" class="edit_text">Name Me</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td>    </tr>');
$('.issue-table > tbody:last').append(row);
$('.edit_text').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'Enter username'
});
```

Comment: dynamic row's style is changed after editing text at dynamic row

Comment: yes, it resolve the functional problem. But, create some styling problem after edit the text at dynamic row what I told at my previous comment. At my static row, no style will change after editing a text. But, after putting your code, styling is changed at dynamic row if I edit any text at there. You can check it at your own fiddle. I can't understand what happened. If you can help me making the code any bug free, I obviously mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for your help

Comment: It is not a bug when you change the value in the input it adds "editable-unsaved" class to it like in your original fiddle too.

Comment: well, I didn't tell style changing of text. I told styling change of dynamic row. If you edit text on the dynamic row(row created by "Create Issue" button), it seems, border or that row will be invisible. If you take a look by browser inspect element, you'll see that dynamic row(tr) has no td after editing text on that row

Comment: Ok I got it. Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/9zP8k/ . You've got to recall editable method.

Answer (score 0):

After appending this text using append function, you need to call

```
$('.edit_text').editable();
```

function. Because without calling this function, there will be not applied jquery to newly appended  tag.

Regards,
Amit